# Map one property from object array to another object in different object array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have two object array. let's say Shop array & Country array. An Shop array's one object has `{id:01,name:'name of the shop',countryCode:'USA'}` and Country array's one object has `{code:'USA', country:'United States of America'}` i want to map shop's object the country code to country's object country an create new object array.in new object array, one object should look like this.

`{id:01,name:'name of the shop',countryCode:'USA',country:'United States of America'}`

what is the most optimized way to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let shopArray=[{id:01,name:'name of the shop',countryCode:'USA'}] 
let countryArray=[{code:'USA', country:'United States of America'}]

let mapedShopArray=shopArray.map(eachShop=>{
    
    for(let eachCountry of countryArray){
        if(eachCountry.code==eachShop.countryCode){
            eachShop.country =eachCountry.country;
            break;
        }
    }

    return eachShop;
})

console.log(mapedShopArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
let shopArr = [{id:01,name:'name of the shop',countryCode:'USA'}];

let countryArr = [{code:'USA', country:'United States of America'}];

let newArr = shopArr.map((shop) => {
   return {...shop, country: countryArr.find(country => {country.code === shop.countryCode}).country};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```js
let shopArrayObj = [{ id: 01, name: "shop1", countryCode: 'USA' },
{ id: 02, name: "shop2", countryCode: 'US' },
{ id: 03, name: "shop3", countryCode: 'ENG' }]

let countryArrayObj = [{ code: 'USA', country: 'United States of America' },
{ code: 'ENG', country: 'England' }]

let finalArrayOb = []

shopArrayObj.map(shop => {
    countryArrayObj.map(country => {
        if (country.code === shop.countryCode) {
            let obj = { ...shop, ...country, }
            delete obj.code
            finalArrayOb.push(obj)
        }
    })
})

console.log(finalArrayOb)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
let country1 = [{code:'USA', country:'United States of America'}]

let shop1 = [{id:01,name:'name of the shop',countryCode:'USA'}]


country1.forEach((item1) => {
    shop1.forEach((item2) => {
        if(item1.code === item2.countryCode) {
            arr.push({'id': item2.id, 'name': item2.name, 'countryCode': item2.countryCode, 'country': item1.country})
        }
    })
})
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as follows.

```
const array1 = [{ id: 1, name:'My Shop', countryCode:'USA' }, { id: 2, name:'My Shop2', countryCode:'UK' }];
const array2 = [{ code:'USA',  country:'United States of America' }, { code:'UK',  country:'United Kingdom' }];

    let myArray = [];

    array1.forEach(item1 => {
      array2.forEach(item2 => {

        if (item1.countryCode === item2.code) {
          let obj = {...item1, country: item2.country };
             myArray.push(obj)
        }
      });
    });
```

**[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mjqd4y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Answer (score 0):

If you can restructure Country as an object, instead of an array, we will be able to achieve the result using single for loop. Working code is given below.

```js
var country = {
    "USA": "United States of America",
    "IN": "India",
    "UAE": "United Arab Emirates",
    "UK": "United Kingdom"
}

var shopArray = [{id:01,name:'name of the shop',countryCode:'USA'}, {id:02,name:'name of another shop',countryCode:'UK'}]

for(var i=0;i<shopArray.length; i++){
    var countryCode = shopArray[i].countryCode;
    shopArray[i].country = country[countryCode];
}

console.log(shopArray)
```

This code will actually modify original shopArray, instead of giving a new array.